# Position element at top right of wrapped text

Tags: html, css

The following simple scenario illustrates the desired result when the text is not wrapped:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.container h1 {
  margin-right: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.container .above {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    The Wrapped Text
    <span class="above">Above</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

If the `margin-right` on the `<h1>` element is increased slightly (forcing the text to wrap) the **Above** text is no longer positioned as desired.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.container h1 {
  margin-right: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
.container .above {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    The Wrapped Text
    <span class="above">Above</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

It's vertical position is correct, but horizontally it is aligned relative to the right edge of the *last word*. Is there a way to horizontally align the **Above** `<span>` relative to the right edge of the *last word on the longest line*? This way the **Above** text would remain at the top right of the text block at all times (wrapped or single line).

Comment: You have probably already tried right:0, but that doesn't solve problem completely...Not sure about pure css solution, waiting for it, too... :)

Comment: Yeah that only causes more problems. Now the **Above** `<span>` is positioned to the right of the `<h1>` (which may have a greater width than the text - and does in my case). Leaving `right` as `unset` somehow seems to automatically position the `<span>` just right of the last word. I'm just wanting to do the same thing except with the *last word on the first line*.

Comment: I think you're expecting too much here. If it gets so narrow that "The" is the only word on the first line, the "Wrapped" on the second line will make the h1 element itself much wider than the "The", even using inline-block or any flex-shrinkery ... so the "Above" would have to creep in to the left by an unspecified and non-quantifiable amount ... I can't see that happen using any current CSS technique available right now.

Comment: And even with simple js fix, in some specific cases - this will not work: https://jsfiddle.net/7ta7v1pf/1/  .above is positioned correctly, but text length in second line makes problem... so, maybe just more advanced js solution could help...

Comment: @CBroe, I see your point, however I am fine with what you are describing. As long as the **Above** text is positioned just to the right of the last word in the longest line that will work. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yeah, but even that's not going to be that easy - even if you inline-block the h1, it will not make it as wide as the text only in all situations, see https://jsfiddle.net/7ta7v1pf/2/

Comment: I think the fiddle by @sinisake is the closest you'll get with pure CSS. And to follow up on CBroe's first comment, should you find a way to accomplish this using too much trickery, there's a risk the next browser update will break the layout.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Looks like (for now at least) I'll be sticking with a JS solution.

Comment: Please post an answer to this question if you stumble upon a solution! I'd love to know :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can try combining `display:flex` on `.container h1` and `vertical-align: super` on `.container .above`.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.container h1 {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
.container .above {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    The Wrapped Text
    <span class="above">Above</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't completely work; the alignment varies depending on what `margin-right` is set to.

Comment: Are you sure? If you are referring to the visual spacing between words "Wrapped" and "Above" when the line is wrapped, this is caused by the actual space character not wrapped. Edit: I see what you mean now!

Comment: Close, but I don't think this quite works. See https://jsfiddle.net/nsLs9d0h/. It appears that when the words wrap "Above" is positioned to the right edge of the `<h1>` element, not the left edge of the text (as is desired). For some reason it seems to work just fine when the text isn't wrapped - just not when it is wrapped.